# Group summary page numbers in crystal reports 2008

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a crystal report which is grouped by Country. Report is total of 1500 pages. I want to show summary like , which grouping country data is starting from which page no. Once report is download in PDF , users can go directly to that page to get the data of that country specific.

For example, Country "UK" data is starting from page no: 800 , "USA " data is starting from page no: "1200", want to show summary page like this

```
Country    pageNo

Australia  75
UK         800
USA        1200
```

Can you please help us , how to achieve this in Crystal reports?

Comment: First of all, you cannot put it on first page without using sub-reports. I tried to google your problem and i found several solutions so don't know why you post your question here if there is already an answer and tutorial how to do this. If you cant find any solution i think  [here](http://scn.sap.com/community/crystal-reports/blog/2013/01/18/how-to-create-an-index-report-and-some-info-on-report-part-linking) or [here](http://scn.sap.com/thread/3323166) is one.

Comment: @shashij....i think your problem got resolved... :)